# How to access Google Drive docs from a server with no browser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I've worked through the examples for performing OOB OAuth2 connections and it works fine from my laptop.

The challenge I'm having is that it fires up a browser, asking me to verify if I want to grant access for my app to the documents in question.  From then on it stores my credential set in a local file and continues to work just fine.

The use case I have is that I have a number of departments in my company that want to leverage Google Docs spreadsheets for reporting.  I then want to be able to run a program on a server (from a cron job) that can scrape this data and build an aggregated report for all departments.

I had intended on creating a "reporting user" that is granted read access to all of the documents in question, then run the report process using that identity.

I tried running it on my laptop, then copying the stored credentials to my server for it to use.  But it seems those credentials are tied to the machine and so it forces a new verification flow via browser.

Any suggestions on how to work with the auth flow for Google Drive to allow me to do what I need?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than needing to grant some user read-only access to all docs, I'd suggest using a service account which has been granted read-only access to all of your Google Apps domain user's docs:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

use:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

as the OAuth scope that you grant the service account access to in the Control Panel. That way if the server is compromised you've limited access to read-only.

Comment: Working through this solution at the moment.  Unfortunately I need to wait for my IT services group to enable the domain wide access.  Then I'll be able to test it further.

Comment: This allows me to get access without the ui hurdle.  Awesome!   Now just to work out why it throws an "access_denied" error when setting the AccountUser for the credential.  But that's another ticket. :)

Comment: sounds like you might have forgotten the actual Control Panel domain delegation: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Comment: I've setup the Team tab of the Project with myself as the Owner.  I haven't added any other teammates.  Then I'm setting setSeriveAccountUser("my-email@gmail.com") and setServiceAccountId("xxx-yyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com").  With the intent of being able to look at a test file I've created under my own account. :-/

Comment: I think you're right.  I tried to circumvent the delay in getting domain wide access from my company and tried building a dummy project using my own personal drive account.  Don't think that's actually comparing apples with apples with the security restrictions.  Guess I'll just have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Create GoogleCredential with p12 file from API console (API Access > Create Another Client ID > Service Account etc):

```
GoogleCredential.Builder#setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(File)
```

[more info on Service Accounts](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better than this, but you can always get a set of credentials and save them in a file for reuse. Getting the credentials could be done with a web browser, but only once, and then your server could use them forever (as long as you request offline access and get a refresh token).

Comment: Thanks Ali, but unfortunately the set of credentials seem to be tied to the machine.  And so if I copy them to the new machine it forces a token refresh cycle.  Which then needs a browser... And so it goes. :)

Comment: No, that is incorrect. The credentials are tied to a client id and client secret, and to a user. Nothing is machine-specific there. Of course, you need to have redirect_uri set up correctly to allow both your machine and the intended server.

Comment: Bizarre.  When I copied the file from my laptop to my desktop it wouldn't accept the token and caused a refresh. :-/

Comment: Just ran it again as I thought I was going insane.  I ran the sample program again on my desktop/server and got a 400 bad request.  Scratched head, ran it again and it worked.  But that's a tangent.